# Two Collection Views in One View Controller iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection Views in One View Controller, First Collection View have class CollectionCellA with imageA as UIImageView! and labelA as UILabel!. Similarly Second Collection View with class CollectionCellB with imageB and labelB. I tried to run with following swift code but it show just blank(white) screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
   var imageArroy = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3"), UIImage(named: "5"), UIImage(named: "6")]
   var imageArroyB = [UIImage(named: "a"), UIImage(named: "b"), UIImage(named: "c"), UIImage(named: "d"), UIImage(named: "e")]
   var labelA: ["Electronics", "Cars", "Pets", "Mobiles", "Food"]
   var labelB: ["UK", "Ireland", "India", "Germany", "Other EU"]

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionViewA: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var CollectionViewB: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CollectionViewA.delegate = self
    CollectionViewB.delegate = self
    CollectionViewA.dataSource = self
    CollectionViewB.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.CollectionViewA {
        return 0 // Replace with count of your data for collectionViewA
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.CollectionViewA {
        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellA", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellA

        // Set up cell
        return cellA
    }
    else {
         let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellB", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellB

        // ...Set up cell
        return cellB
    }
}
```

Comment: What is UILabelView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for Two Collection View in One View Controller with images and label.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.CollectionViewA {
            return imageArroy.count
        }

        return imageArroyB.count 

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.CollectionViewA {
            let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellA", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellA
            cellA.imageA.image = imageArroyB[indexPath.row]
            cellA.labelA.text = labelA[indexPath.row]
            // Set up cell
            return cellA
        }

        else {
             let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellB", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellB
            cellB.imageB.image = imageArroyB[indexPath.row]
            cellB.labelB.text = labelB[indexPath.row]
            // ...Set up cell

            return cellB
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me below code works like a charm . you should send/assign value in cellForItemAt indexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.CollectionViewA {
            return imageArroy.count
        }

        return imageArroyB.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.CollectionViewA {
            let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellA", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellA
            // Set up cell
            cellA.lbl.text = labelA[indexPath.row]

            return cellA
        }

        else {
            let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellB", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCellB
            // ...Set up cell
            cellB.lbl.text = labelB[indexPath.row]

            return cellB
        }
    }
}


class CollectionCellA : UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

}

class CollectionCellB : UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , You are almost there. But problem is images are not visible in output. When I added cellA.imageA.image = imageArroy[indexPath.row] and cellB.imageB.image = imageArroyB[indexPath.row] for  both numberOfItemsInSection it works fantastic. The codes for this have posted.

Comment: great i posted this answer as sample . if it worked for you then great

Answer (score 1):

> Add two collection view and connect delegate and data source with view countroller,create collection view cell and connect with cell and outlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionview1: UICollectionView!
var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Frid","Sat"]
var dayTask = [String]()

var task = [["Sun1","Mon1","Tues1","Wed1","Thur1","Frid1","Sat1"],["Sun2","Mon2","Tue2","Wed2"],["Sun3","Mon3","Tues3","Wed3","Thur3","Frid3","Sat3"],["Sun4","Mon4"],["Sun5","Mon5","Tues5","Wed5","Thur5","Frid5","Sat5"],["Sun6","Mon6","Tues6","Wed6"],["Sun7","Mon7","Tues7","Wed7","Thur7"]]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dayTask = task[0]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

> Collection view data source and delgate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == collectionview1{
        return days.count
    }else{
       return dayTask.count
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell1", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

    if collectionView == collectionview1{
        cell.label.text = days[indexPath.row]
        let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        collectionViewLayout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 40)
        collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()
    }else
    {
        let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        collectionViewLayout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 40)
        collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()
        cell.label.text = dayTask[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == collectionview1{
        dayTask = task[indexPath.row]
        collectionView2.reloadData()
    }
}
```